# Can the path include negative entries (exceptions to a wildcard)?

Tags: filesystem, load

Is there a way to exclude specific files and directories from Vim's `path`?

I was hoping a syntax like this would work:

```
set path+=./**,!./ignoredirectory,!./ignoredirectory2,!./ignorefile.txt
```

I would use `wildignore` but I don't think it supports relative path expansion if I used something like `set wildignore+=ignoredirectory,ignoredirectory2,ignorefile.txt`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish? Your example doesn't make any sense, what behaviour exactle do you want?

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of experimentation with `wildignore`. I don't think it supports relative paths, or even absolute paths.

Here's what I have:

1. A file at `~/devel/scratchpad/c++/ms.cpp`
2. Vim opened with current directory `~/devel`
3. `:set path=~/devel/**`

I tried:

```
set wildignore=scratchpad/**/*
set wildignore=~/devel/scratchpad/**/*
set wildignore=./scratchpad/**/*
set wildignore=/home/muru/devel/scratchpad/**/*
set wildignore=*/scratchpad/**/*
set wildignore=**/scratchpad/**/*
```

Only the last two prevented tab completion from filling `:find ms.` to `:find ms.cpp`. I'm not sure how to explain the results.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think such a syntax should work?

`:h :set` is your entry point to Vim's documentation on `:set`. Scroll down a little to find out how to remove an item from a comma-separated list:

```
:set path-=whatever
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to append `**` to the path, and then remove specific files and directories that would be matched by `**`. I cannot remove a specific file using `set path-=whatever` when I use the wildcard `**` .

Comment: Use `:help wildignore` to ignore specific directories and files.

Comment: I dont believe that `wildignore` supports relative paths..

Comment: Observation is better than belief.